# Counterexample or proof for partitioning a set of finite Lebesgue measure into two

Tags: real-analysis

Can you please provide a counterexample or proof to:
"Every set of ﬁnite Lebesgue measure can be partitioned into two subsets of equal measure"
I know it has to do with the unboundedness. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: sets where? Partitioned how?

Comment: I am just quoting a comprehensive exam question. Here is my answer to your question 1)the Lebesgue measure is defined on R^n 2) partitioned in just the usual sense ex. (0,1)= (0,1/2)\cup (1/2,1)

Comment: The "Ham Sandwich Theorem" of the title has a lot more to it than just the partitioning of sets into subsets of equal measure. If your question really has something to do with the Ham Sandwich Theorem, then there are some important conditions missing in your question.

Comment: Is there really a counterexample? For each unit vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is the hyperplane through the origin normal to $u$, and the vector $u$ serves to define a half-space. If none of these hyperplanes bisect the set $A$ then to each $u$ we can assign $1$ if there is more of $A$ on the $u$ side of the hyperplane, else $-1$ if there is less. Naively it seems this gives a continuous map $g$ from the $n-1$ sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into the set $\{1,-1\}$ for which $g(-u)=-g(u).$ That seems impossible on considering a path in the sphere from $u$ to $-u.$